# How do I construct Claims after successful ADFS authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, adfs, claims-based-identity

Our app redirects to an external ADFS login for auth then routes back to us. I'm trying to figure out how I parse out the claims info once it returns to our site. The trouble I've run into is finding a working example for .NET Core 2.1. Here is what I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
               .AddWsFederation(options => {                   
                   options.MetadataAddress = config.Authentication.ADFSMetadataAddress;
                   options.Wtrealm = config.Authentication.ADFSWtrealm;
                   options.CallbackPath = "/Auth";
               }).AddCookie();
```

This part works fine, I can login and get sent back to my application. The examples on the Microsoft documentation show implementing a custom `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` like this to extract the claims info:

```
public class MyClaimsAuthenticationManager : ClaimsAuthenticationManager {
        public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal) {
            if (incomingPrincipal != null && incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true) {
                ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
            }
        return incomingPrincipal;
    }
}
```

But it cannot find that base class in .NET Core. I tried adding NuGet packages for:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core
```

and even

```
System.Security.Claims
```

but no dice...is there another way to accomplish this in .NET Core?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? All claims that are passed from your external authentication provider will be automatically persisted in the created principal that is persisted by the Cookie scheme. So you can just access the claims there. Or do you want to add _additional_ claims on top of those?

Comment: @poke - yes there may be additional claims required, that's how I started looking into these examples. But for the moment I'd just like to see what is available that is getting sent back from ADFS? My 'CallbackPath' is set to a controller named Auth. What do I code there to see the claims stored in the cookie?

Comment: The callback path for external authentication providers will automatically intercepted by your external authentication scheme. So you cannot “call back” to a controller action. The scheme will retrieve the message from the auth provider and then sign in with the cookie scheme, so _afterwards_ you can access the signed-in user simply by looking at the `User` in your controller. To see the claims, just look at `User.Claims`.

Comment: That being said, to modify your claims, you can use a [`ClaimsTransformer`](https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/blob/c0eabc39e37d4d8a7765593dc02604db1cfdb001/samples/ClaimsTransformation/ClaimsTransformer.cs) or alternatively register an event for the [WsFederation scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.wsfederation.wsfederationevents?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that modifies the principal before the sign-in is done (use the `OnTicketReceived` event for that).

Comment: @poke Yes I see that now, when it first hits that Auth path i can't access the user identity in the controller for that, but once that is completed the User and the Claims are available (in my home controller for example). What's the best way to do this then, if you want to pull out some of these claims values and make a db query based on them for example?

Comment: If you just want to retrieve the claim values, just use e.g. `User.FindFirst("claim-type")`. You can do that anywhere within a controller action to retrieve a claim for the current user. If you want to *modify* the claims before the principal is signed in, then check out the claims transformer or the `OnTicketReceived` event as written before.

Comment: Need to do this with MVC 5 app that is a relying party of ADFS 4